# get Button to subtract value mulitple times tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to create a button that'll decrease the value of an integer. It works once (going from 10 to 9), but I cannot get it to go from 9 to 8.

```
from tkinter import *

w = Tk()
w.geometry('500x500')

integer = 10

def subtract():
    new_integer = integer - 1
    l1.config(text=new_integer)

l1 = Label(w, text=integer, bg='white', fg='black')
l1.config(height=2, width=7)
l1.grid(row=1, column=1)

b1 = Button(w, text='<<< 1', bg='black', fg='white', command=subtract)
b1.config(height=2, width=7)
b1.grid(row=1, column=0)

w.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never update the value of `new_integer`.

Try:

```
integer = 10

def subtract():
    global integer
    integer = integer - 1
    l1.config(text=integer)
```

Comment: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'integer' referenced before assignment
Exception in Tkinter callback

Comment: Oops.  Yeah, you have to declare `integer` as a global.  See the update

Answer (score 1):

you varible will always caculate 10 - 1, you need to update it like this

```
def subtract():
    global integer
    new_integer = integer - 1
    integer -= 1
    l1.config(text=new_integer)
```